# How to save ODocument in map field in Vertex with Java

Tags: java, orientdb

Assuming I have a Vertex (let's call it "PokemonMaster")

```
PokemonMaster
{
 name, (STRING)
 age, (INTEGER)
 pokemons, (EMBEDDEDMAP) of Pokemon
}
```

in my DB containing an EMBEDDEDMAP (I also tried with LINKMAP but I'm not sure of what i'm doing) of a class "Pokemon".

I'm trying with Java to create the Vertex and put in the field "pokemons", some pokemons.

let's say a Pokemon looks like :

```
Pokemon
{
  name, (STRING)
}
```

I'm doing something like :

```
Vertex v = graph.addVertex("class:PokemonMaster",
                           "name", "Sacha",
                           "age", "42",
                           "pokemons", new ODocument("Pokemon").field("name", "Pikachu"));
```

I assume this would create a first element (Pikachu) in the map. And I was hoping to be able to add some Pokemons to my map later by doing something like :

```
v.setProperty("pokemons", new ODocument("Pokemon").field("name", "Raichu"));
```

All of this is actually not working and that's why i'm here, am I totally wrong?

I get the error :

```
The field 'PokemonMaster.pokemons' has been declared as EMBEDDEDMAP but an incompatible type is used. Value: Pokemon{name:Pikachu}
```

Thank you !

### Edit

I found the solution.
Creating a map like :

```
Map<String, ODocument> foo = new HashMap<>();
```

Putting some pokemons in it :

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument("Pokemon").field("name", "Pikachu");
ODocument doc2 = new ODocument("Pokemon").field("name", "Raichu");
foo.put("pikachu", doc);
foo.put("raichu", doc2);
doc.save();
doc2.save();
```

and simply giving the map as parameter :

```
Vertex v = graph.addVertex("class:PokemonMaster",
                           "name", "Sacha",
                           "age", "42",
                           "pokemons", foo);
```

Hope it will help someone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

In case of embeddedmap, to create the schema:

```
    OrientGraphNoTx graphOne = new OrientGraphNoTx(URL, USER, USER);
    try {
        OSchema schema = graphOne.getRawGraph().getMetadata().getSchema();

        OClass pokemon = schema.createClass("Pokemon");
        pokemon.createProperty("name", OType.STRING);

        OClass vClass = schema.getClass("V");
        OClass pokemonMaster = schema.createClass("PokemonMaster");
        pokemonMaster.setSuperClass(vClass);
        pokemonMaster.createProperty("name", OType.STRING);
        pokemonMaster.createProperty("age", OType.INTEGER);
        pokemonMaster.createProperty("pokemons", OType.EMBEDDEDMAP, pokemon);
    } finally {
        graphOne.shutdown();
    }
```

Create a master with a pokemon:

```
    String pmRID = "";

    OrientGraph graphTwo = new OrientGraph(URL, USER, USER);
    try {
        ODocument pokemon = new ODocument("Pokemon");
        pokemon.field("name", "Pikachu");
        Map<String,ODocument> foo = new HashMap();
        foo.put("pikachu", pokemon);

        OrientVertex v = graphTwo.addVertex("class:PokemonMaster",
                "name", "Sacha",
                "age", "42",
                "pokemons", foo);

        graphTwo.commit();
        pmRID = v.getIdentity().toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        graphTwo.shutdown();
    }
```

Add a second pokemon:

```
    OrientGraph graphThree = new OrientGraph(URL, USER, USER);
    try {
        ODocument pokemon = new ODocument("Pokemon");
        pokemon.field("name", "Raichu");

        OrientVertex v = graphThree.getVertex(pmRID);
        Map<String, ODocument> pokemons = v.getProperty("pokemons");
        if (pokemons == null) {
            pokemons = new HashMap();
        }
        pokemons.put("raichu", pokemon);
        v.setProperty("pokemons", pokemons);

        graphThree.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    } finally {
        graphThree.shutdown();
    }
```

---

You could also use an embeddedlist. See [here](https://gist.github.com/vitorenesduarte/164ded0bc52bf0e4418b).

Comment: Pretty cool thank you, in my case i'll need a map more than a list but this will be usefull later. Just to be sure, the difference between a embeddedlist and a linklist is that in embeddedlist we're pushing an element in it, and in linklist we'ere creating a link to an element already in the DB?

Comment: And is there a way to get the map the same way you get your list? When you're doing "List<ODocument> pokemons = v.getProperty("pokemons");" I tried in my case "Map<String, ODocument> pokemons = v.getProperty("pokemons");" and it's not working, telling me "com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterable cannot be cast to java.util.Map"

Comment: Actually it worked, with an OrientElementIterable<Element> instead of the map, but if someone knows why it does not want to cast it to Map i'd like to know

Comment: Thank i'll try, the way i did with the Map was may be wrong

Comment: I did what you did and it works fine, but I think the difference is that I was using LINKMAP and not EMBEDDEDMAP, and i can't figure out how to get the property "pokemons" into a java map with LINKMAP. As I said it works with OrientElementIterable<Element> but it is a list of pokemons and i'm losing the key/value feature of maps here

Comment: Your question says EMBEDDEDMAP and not LINKMAP.

Comment: Yes sorry it's just that i'm curious and i'm trying it in differents ways so I mixed up everything, now i want it to be in LINKMAP, and it works i'm able to create the elements etc. But i can't "Get" it into a map as it's able to do when it's an Embeddedmap

Comment: Then you could aprove this answer and open another one. If you do this, other people can find answers to their problems easily.

Comment: Ok thank you, seems like I can't approve, I need more reputation, but i'll do it as soon as i can